# PHP: How to load page before dynamic content has finished loading

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form which uses `get` to post data to a form processing page, which then redirects to another page where lots of dynamic content is created.

```
<form action="/form-process.php"  method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input id="url" type="text" name="url" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

```php
//form-process.php
$url = $_GET['url'];
//dynamic URL, doesn't load until all content has finished processing
// I need it to load immediately to display loaders.
header('Location: /check/' . $url); php
```

The problem I'm having is that the dynamic URL doesn't load in the browser until all the content of the page has finished loading.

I need the dynamic URL to load in the browser straight away before it has finished loading, because I then intend to show some ajax loaders for each piece of dynamic content and also a 'please wait' loading message.

I'm brand new to ajax so unsure whether it can achieve this. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are your ajax calls?

Comment: I don't have any ajax in my code whatsoever at the moment because I didn't know if that would accomplish my problem. I don't know ajax.